# Track if a user has watched a video and reward them.?

Tags: php, javascript, video

I own a incentive site where users complete offers and earn points to purchase items. I'm looking for a way to implement videos into it. A user watches a video all the way through and earns a certain number of points to their account. The site is in PHP and the there is a users table in my database that keeps track of the users points.

Any idea how to check if the user has watched the video?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you asking if they looked at the video? or watched the entire video?

Comment: I think the best you can hope for is that the user played the entire video - who knows if they actually sat and watched it.

Comment: Just add some very easy facts to the video(s), at different times, and ask the user for them. If he knows the answer, he either must have watched the video or looked up the facts. To prevent the latter, you'll have to generate the video dynamically.

Comment: Looked at the video is most important, because will be generating revenue from the ads that are being played at the beginning the video. I have no preference if they actually watch the content, as long as the revenue comes in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you just want to catch events in the Youtube embedded player, check out their JS API documentation about [Subscribing to events](https://code.google.com/intl/sv-SE/apis/youtube/js_api_reference.html#SubscribingEvents). There's also a [list of events](https://code.google.com/intl/sv-SE/apis/youtube/js_api_reference.html#Events) you can listen to.

Answer (score 2):

You can go to great lengths in trying to prevent cheating but you still won't catch every last cheater out there since its always possible to cheat the client software.

Stream the video in realtime (where you control the streaming bandwidth so that it's not possible to download the entire video at once), for example from a serverside script, and note the view when the entire video is streamed.

It will always be possible to cheat, though. The user may write a script which just pretends to be a visitor and "view" the video in the background. You can try to prevent this by utilising encryption or obfuscation of some kind, but it's always possible to circumvent since the user can control the clientside as they see fit.

The user may still just mute their speakers and play the video in a minimised window. You can't control this perfectly, although maye you can utilise the `blur` event in JavaScript to pause the video (in that case, send a signal to the server as well and pause the streaming). They can still leave the computer, though (but that's probably uncommon, and your paying clients will certainly know and consider that risk already).

Comment: lets say its a youtube video for example. all i care about is if they watched the ad at the beginning of the video, whether they actually pay attention to the content is irrelevant. Any way to check that the user has clicked play on the embedded flash player?

Answer (score 1):

You can use EventListener. You capture the time when video is started. Then you can capture it again in the EventListener "ended" function, after that you calculate the watching time against skipping to end of the video. If video time and watching time is same, you can post to your php that he watched that movie.

Comment: At least and minus a certain amount would probably be best; exact time might be hard to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

The "ended" event should be what you're looking for.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <link type="text/css" href="style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    </head>
    <body>

        <video id="movie" src="movie.mov" autoplay="true"></video>

        <script>

            document.getElementById("movie").addEventListener("ended", function(){alert("all done")}, true);

            </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What if they skip to the end of the video?

Comment: In addition to what Emil suggested below, perhaps running a timer that ends about 5 seconds before the movie ends can be used to ensure that the entire video is watched. However, as has been said, there's no foolproof way to achieve this.

Comment: lets say its a youtube video for example. all i care about is if they watched the ad at the beginning of the video, whether they actually pay attention to the content is irrelevant. Any way to check that the user has clicked play on the embedded flash player?